# Adding url parameters with redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to pass url parameters with this type of redirect_to?

```
redirect_to contact_path(@contact), :show_family => 'yes'
```

I want a URL that results in:

```
/contacts/1?show_family=yes
```

Comment: Note: the above provided redirect_to doesn't seem to work at the moment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, just pass your query string parameters in to `contact_path`:

```
redirect_to contact_path(@contact, :show_family => 'yes')
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works great.  Silly me didn't even think about including that parameter inside the parenthesis.